# Why can't I assign NSPredicate with NSFetchRequest?

Tags: swift

I tried making a simple query from table Message where `senderId = "10001"`, and when I tried running this code, I received the following error:

> Cannot assign a value of type NSPredicate to a value of type NSFetchRequest

Here is my code:

```
  let appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        let context3: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Messages")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
        request = NSPredicate(format: "senderID = %@", argumentArray: ["10001"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to assign NSPredicate to NSFetchRequest. You need            `request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "senderID = %@", argumentArray: ["10001"])`

Comment: Thank You, O MY GOD i spend 2 hours I'm so stupiiid.